# Confirming that only numbers are contained in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get this code to return just the one false alert, since it contains a number when I'm checking that what's in the string "name" should all be lowercase alphas?

```
var name = "Bob1";
var i = 0; 
var name = name.toLowerCase()

for(i=0; i<name.length; i++){
  if((name.charCodeAt(i)>96) && (name.charCodeAt(i)<123)) {
    alert("true");
  } else {alert("false");}
}
```

Comment: . @Aquillo suggestion to use regex is a much cleaner version altogether but if you want the for loop break; is command your looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with regex for this one:

```
if(name.match(/\d/)) {
    // this contains at least one number
}
else {
    // this doesn't contain any numbers
}
```

Since people will notice the upvoted answer, I will reference an even better solution for your case. This is mentioned by Ray Toal (credits / upvotes to him for this case):

Since you only want to allow undercase alpha's for your `name`, you can handle this directly too (this will cover issues with hyphens et cetera too):

```
if(name.match(/^[a-z]+$/)) {
    // this contains only undercase alpha's
}
else {
    // this contains at least one character that's not allowed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alert that all characters are in the range `a` through `z` you can use a regex that says that directly

```
alert(/^[a-z]+$/.test(name1.toLowerCase()))
```

You can also invert the condition and say that you want the value `false` if the string contains at least one non-letter:

```
alert(!(/[^a-z]/.test(name1.toLowerCase())))
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `break` statement so new code would look like this inside the if statement

```
if((name.charCodeAt(i)>96) && (name.charCodeAt(i)<123))
 {alert("true");
   break;
 }else
```

... basically it just exits the for loop (same command works in while loops as well)

Comment: ... @Aquillo suggestion to use regex is a much cleaner version altogether but if you want the for loop `break;` is command your looking for

Answer (score 0):

put a break; inside the else , so that it gets out of the loop after alerting false for the first time